# protractor do all API functions really return promises?

Tags: angularjs, testing, promise, protractor

When I ran this test:

```
browser.get('http://www.valid-site.com').then(function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

I'm expecting 1 or true to be printed to indicate that the operation is successful since get() should return a promise with the value it has been resolved to. Instead it prints 'null'. In the API docs http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api there is no indication of a return type. I'm confused which functions return a promise and which do not.

Comment: To clarify, `get()` is *always* returning a promise.  (That is what the `then` is being invoked on.)  You're asking if promises always have a *value* when they resolve.  They do not.  You can resolve a promise without providing a value.  (In your case the `console.log` will not execute until the promise is resolved, so the fact of its execution is an indication that the page was gotten.)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it would directly answer the question, but, if you look into the [`browser.get()` protractor's implementation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/45341c944bf60537849776c7f362ee0442b219e6/lib/protractor.js#L437) (it wraps the `WebDriverJS`'s `driver.get()`), you can see that it returns:

```
return this.executeScript_(
  'angular.resumeBootstrap(arguments[0]);',
  msg('resume bootstrap'),
  moduleNames);
```

And since the executed script has no `return`, this is the reason you see `null` resolved.

---

But, if you look into, for example, [`browser.refresh()` implementation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/45341c944bf60537849776c7f362ee0442b219e6/lib/protractor.js#L525), you'll see that it returns:

```
return self.executeScript_(
  'return window.location.href',
  'Protractor.refresh() - getUrl').then(function(href) {
    return self.get(href, timeout);
  });
```

In this case, the executed script returns `window.location.href` value, which you would see on the console in case:

```
browser.refresh().then(function (url) {
    console.log(url);
});
```

---

I guess, you can understand this ["Read the source, Luke" answer](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/), as, whenever you are not sure, look into sources.